# Typed aggregation in UML

Tags: kotlin, templates, types, uml, class-diagram

In the following UML class diagram, I would like to make it apparent that the `Course.chapters` and `Chapter.sections` members are implemented by `AugmentedList<Chapter>` and `AugmentedList<Section>` respectively.

[image]

I know that images should be avoided on SO, so here is the Kotlin code corresponding to this diagram.

```kotlin
interface AugmentedList<E>: List<E> {
  val introduction: String
  val conclusion: String
}

interface Section

interface Chapter {
  val sections: AugmentedList<Section>
}

interface Course {
  val chapters: AugmentedList<Chapter>
}
```

I know the way of binding a templated class to a non-templated class is through [binding](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/template.html#template-binding), however I would like to avoid adding a "concrete" interface to the diagram, since the interfaces `AugmentedList<Chapter>` and `AugmentedList<Section>` will not be implemented explicitly in the code.

Maybe there is a stereotype for interfaces that are not implemented but just used in the UML diagram?

I also looked at adding a qualifier `chapters: AugmentedList<Chapter>` to the `Course` interface but I feel like this is not the purpose of qualifiers.

Is there a correct way to be precise about how composition will be implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warning in your diagram *chapters* and *sections* are on the wrong side, they must be on the same side than the multiplicities `0..*`.

---

If you do not want to show the named bound classes like *ChapterList* and *SectionList* like in :

[image]

you can use anonymous bound classes (see figure 9.6 *Anonymous Bound Class* page 106 of [formal/2017-12-05](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1) ) :

[image]

and if you do not want to even show them you can use attributes to show the properties :

[image]

Anyway if you want to draw your compositions you can do something like :

[image]

which clearly (even if not formally) indicates how the chapters/sections are memorized. Of course in theory you have to define the stereotype *AugmentedList*, extending the metaclasse *Association* typically for model to code transforming being one of the reason to extend UML (see § 12.3.1.1 *Positioning Profiles versus Metamodels, MOF and UML* page 252 and 253 of [formal/2017-12-05](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1) )

In the diagrams I use some dependencies `<<use>>` to highlight the links between classes, they are not mandatory and you can have them for instance directly between *Course* and *Chapter* and between *Chapter* and *Section* when it is not already the case.

Comment: I like your answer except for the last suggestion to use a stereotype to indicate the usage of  a specific interface for a relation. Stereotypes belong in the meta-model, and should be defined in the profile that is used for a certain model. The fact that a relation uses a specific interface for it's realization is a dependency on the model level, not a meta-model property.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer! I have not decided yet which format I'll use, thank you for the pointers also!